# Trying to center <img> in container in navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a logo I am trying to center brand logo in a navbar on the left but centered in the box.

Here is what I currently have:

[image]

Here is the styling

```
<style>
    .navbar {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        background-color: #E0E0E0;
        z-index: 9999;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 12px !important;
        line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        border-radius: 0;
    } 
    .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
        color: #000000 !important;
    }

    .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
        color: #000000 !important;
        background-color: #fff !important;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
        border-color: transparent;
        color: #fff !important;
    }  

    .jumbotron {
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }

    footer .glyphicon {
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        color: #000000;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        border: 2px solid black;
    }

</style>

<body>
    <!-- add navigation bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="index/img/manchucorp_black.svg" alt="" width="40" height45="40">
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavBar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li> 
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

I have been driving myself nuts making new div's, containers etc etc and just cannot seem to get the image in the center of the black box.

```css
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #000000 !important;
}
.navbar-nav li a:hover,
.navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #000000 !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff !important;
}
.jumbotron {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
footer .glyphicon {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar-brand {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <!-- add navigation bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="" width="40" height="40">
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavBar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#team">Team</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: How do you want it to behave? Should the image resize to fit within box? Should the box resize to fit around the image? Do you want to keep any specific padding?

Comment: it just needs to be in the center of the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.navbar-brand {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

.navbar-brand > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Try this one. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

Add `display:inline-table` property in `navbar-brand` selector.

**Note :** `display:inline-block` may not giving as needed.

```css
.navbar {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        background-color: #E0E0E0;
        z-index: 9999;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 12px !important;
        line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        border-radius: 0;
} 
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
        border-color: transparent;
        color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-brand {
        border: 2px solid black;
        display:inline-table;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- add navigation bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="//lorempixel.com/500/500/" width="40" height="40">
        </a>Image include inside the box.
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't mind that use bootstrap that i never.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #000000 !important;
}
.navbar-nav li a:hover,
.navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #000000 !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff !important;
}
.jumbotron {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
footer .glyphicon {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #000000;
}
a.navbar-brand {
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <!-- add navigation bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="" width="40" height="40">
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavBar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#team">Team</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

This is a case where you have to fight against bootstrap...

```
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: center; /* added this */
}

a.navbar-brand { /* better target of element */
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: none; /* removed bootstrap's float */
  display: inline-block; /* removed bootstrap's display */
}
```